Pagespeed reports "Serves images with low resolution"
On my website, I have a logo of nice quality in PNG that is 131 x 130px that I put in the viewport in the corner.
When I ran it through pagespeed insights, the mobile tab gives me the error shown but clicking on the desktop tab I don't see the error.

So I tried img srcset as shown in the picture and that didn't help.
I also tried media queries to fix the image size since I also have an image that is now half the size.
What I'm ultimately trying to do now is make the smaller image load if the screen width is under 400 pixels (for mobile devices). Otherwise the regular image will load instead.
The only way I could prevent pagespeed from complaining is if I appended 1x and 2x after each filename in srcset but when I tested the page, only one image size loaded. I tried clearing cache and that didn't help.
How do I properly fix this problem so pagespeed insights won't complain?
and as a side note: Why is it expecting a larger image size from me?

It's about pixel density, which is a slightly different thing to screen resolution.
Whereas on a standard desktop monitor, a 1px x 1px area will contain a single pixel of the image - mobile (and hi-res) screens can contain more information in the same space.
You haven't said how you tested the page when you add 1x and 2x versions, but if you viewed the page on a monitor that has a higher pixel density, then the 2x version should show. This 2x version should be twice the size as your 1x version.  This takes up the same amount of space on screen, but that extra image information means that it then has enough data to keep it sharp.
The reason the desktop PageSpeed Insights report does not warn you of this is because hi-res desktop monitors are rare, so they don't simulate one in their tests.
PageSpeed Insights' mobile browser expects images to be at least 1.5x the display size.
Note that there are plenty of other screens which you could optimise for should you want - PageSpeed Insights does not cover them all.   They just cover the average user.

As said above, it's really not about resolution, it's about pixel density.
I would generally recommend you to switch to vector format of logo in .svg. Then you will get rid of such problems, and the logo will scale without loss of pixel density.
